# Is there a standard place to find detailed wiring circuit and component information for different aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, electrical-system

Today I was looking into the systems that are affected by the STDBY ATTD (#1 and #2) circuit breakers in a SR22 and I accidentally stumbled upon something that I find very interesting and I've been searching for some time now.

In the Wiring Manual (WM) chapter 91-00 I found a really big table with circuit load charts. For example: GPS 1 has a 1.12 A current drain at 28 VDC.

Now here come my questions:

1. Will I be able to find this information in all Wiring Manuals in chapter 91-00? According to [the ATA chapter list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_100), chapter 91 is just for charts. Do all aircraft manufactures have a circuit load chart at chapter 91-00 or is it just Cirrus?
2. Is there a standard place in the manuals where I can find the power requirements of each component for any plane or manufacturer? I'm interested in a manual name and a chapter preferably.

Comment: I don't really understand your questions. For the first one, are you asking if Cirrus follows the ATA chapter numbering? For the second, are you asking where you can find this information for *any* aircraft, or just for the SR22?

Comment: The SR22 wiring manual is [p/n 13775](http://servicecenters.cirrusdesign.com/techpubs/pdf/WM/SR22/pdf/coverpage.pdf)

Comment: @Pondlife I've updated the question. I know that it follows the ATA chapter list, but at 91-00 it just says charts, doesn't say It has to have the circuit loads. I want to know if I'm looking for circuit loads should I be looking in the WM at chapter 91 or in a different manual ?

Comment: Electrical power is covered in ATA Chapter 24.  Look to subsection -50 for AC power distribution, -60 for DC power distribution, and -70 for Primary and Secondary Power.  The first two typically deal with individual loads.  The last covers the major distribution busses.